# Vue router TypeError issue causing site not to render

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I've been fiddling with Vue for a side project and have been trying to implement routing using `vue-router`, but I can't seem to find a solution to this TypeError I'm getting, which is preventing the site to load at all on localhost:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parent') vue-router.mjs:2478
```

Here is how I've set up each of my files:

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

**router.js**

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import About from "@/views/About.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: "/about",
        name: "About",
        component: About,
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: routes,
});

export default router;
```

**App.vue**

```html
<script setup>
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.vue";
</script>

<template>
    <RouterView />
    <Navbar />
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

**Navbar.vue**

```html
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom">
        <RouterLink class="navbar-brand" to="/">
            <span class="navbar-brand-logo"></span>
        </RouterLink>
    ...
    </nav>
</template>
```

**Home.vue**

```html
<template>This is the homepage.</template>
```

**About.vue**

```html
<template>This is the about page.</template>
```

I'm rocking Vue `v3.2.41` and `vue-router v4.1.6`. Not exactly sure what's going wrong here. When I pull out `use(router)` from `main.js`, the navbar I have renders, so it's clearly something going wrong with vue-router. Would appreciate any help with it!

Comment: Usually you need a `div` or any other tag/component inside of the `template` rather than just some text. Please provide such node to your DOM by nested the bare test sentence into a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.vue` or anywhere you want to re-use your component make sure to define your imported component in a `components` property like this:

```
<script>
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.vue";

export default {
...

components: {
  Navbar
},

</script>
```